# How to replace uploaded image with Phoenix and Arc?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I use Arc to upload images - it's basic structure of uploader - I don't do any custom or fancy actions there - validate, transform or filename are all similar to the ones in [example](https://github.com/stavro/arc).

I want to replace my uploaded image and as I see in `uploads` folder, where I store them- everything is fine, but in my app as I check want to use `url/2` like this:

```
Avatar.url({file, scope}, :thumb)
```

it returns me url to the old file and sometimes this old file is broken- rendered only partially. Using `mix phoenix.server` doesn't change the situation. Is there any weird cache? I could use nasty work-around to ensure that file `thumb.png` is deleted, whenever it exists, but is there any different way?

**TL;DR**: How to replace the uploaded image with the same name to make sure that new usage of `url` (provided by Arc.Storage.Local or Arc.Storage.S3) will work properly?

Comment: I haven't used Arc before, but it could be that your browser is aggressively caching the image. Try either clearing your cache or opening the same page in a different browser.

Comment: It was my first thought- tested on Chrome, Firefox and IE11 - everyone with new clear session - result is the same.

Comment: I think I have seen something on their github issues page, arc didn't take care of the delete action. For the moment I think we have to use a work-around to do it. I had the same problem with deleting associated model which didn't remove the image.

Comment: Here is the link: https://github.com/stavro/arc_ecto/issues/40 you might find some idea for the temporary work-around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest work around in this case for me was to name differently each new uploaded image. To do so I used additional field in schema which holds the `logo_number` (I didn't wanted to name it id) and ensure that all of old files are deleted with simple usage of `File` module functions - namely `ls` and `rm!`.